# How to make floating content over fixed video HTML?

Tags: html, css

The web page has background video with `position: fixed`.

Below video there is `<div>` with the main content.

How can I make this content floating over video?

This is my experemental page: oleg-s-fresh-site-8f277a.webflow.io

You can see that content is not floaring over video, it is sctolled with video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code:

```
.ssssss {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Remove the z-index property from .mm class. You don't need it and PRESTO!

Comment: Glad I could help  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the div is just above the video, i purpose to use this code;

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
z-index:9999; <---- for example
//backgro.. bla bla...
```

If this code doesn't work, try to add `z-index:1;` to your video.

---

What is z-index ?

Z-index is a way to align in a Y position.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wteWH.png)

PS : more info = http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I have this code, but it does not work, so video is showed as background, but content is not scrolled.

Comment: So you are saying that the video is there and your content is behind the video ? If it's that, the z-index should work. Check your float div width, height, background, opacity, display...